# Flat File Schema Wizard

Tags: xsd, biztalk, flat-file

I have an example of a tab delimited flat file like this:

```
Expense Report Id   Name    Geography   StartDate   EndDate TotalExpense    
123456789   JJ Thompson Atlanta 6/12/2011   6/18/2011   454.10  
ExpenseDate Guests (Separated by comma) CompanyAffiliation  Establishment   Project
6/14/2011   "Norm McDonald, Gary Shandling" Two Guys Hamburgers Little Debbie's MumboJumbo
6/16/2011       IBN Yo  MumboJumbo  Conceirge
6/18/2011   Jimi Hendrix    The Experience  Electric Ladyland   MumboJumbo  Client
```

I have to convert an xml schema to look like this tab delimited flat file. Any idea how when using the flat file schema wizard to keep the headers in there? I can do it w/out the headers no problem

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create a top level header element that is max occurs 1 and min occurs 1 that has a field for each column header with a default value.  You would need to map a non repeating node on the left to this header element so that it is created.